# Want to use a string to name a new instance of a class dynamically

Tags: c#, string, function, xna, naming

Ok, this may be impossible but I want to use a string taken as an argument to a function and use that string to name a new instance of a class. Using visual studios 2010 with C# XNA, I tried searching for solutions using google and here but maybe I'm not using the right keywords  or something.

```
     public void createRace(string raceName, Element element1, Element element2, AbilityScore stat1, AbilityScore stat2, AbilityScore stat3, AbilityScore stat4)
    {
        Race temp = new Race();
        temp.raceName = raceName;
        temp.primaryElement = element1;
        temp.secondaryElement = element2;
        temp.primaryAbility = stat1;
        temp.secondaryAbility1 = stat2;
        temp.secondaryAbility2 = stat3;
        temp.weakAbility = stat4;
    }
```

I want Race temp to use raceName instead of temp when naming the new instance of Race, if it's not possible let me know and I'll find a workaround.

Comment: Why do you need this requirement, The compiler is not really going to care what you name your variables

Comment: It is not possible (since variable name is compile time, but value of variable is run-time), but since you didn't explain why you want that name to be different it is not clear what is proper workaround. `Dictionary` as suggested by TGH may be what you want...

Comment: One could argue that you could use a constructor (or object initializer) for creating instances of `Race` - and that you don't need the `createRace` method at all.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a dictionary to solve this. The following code will allow you "raceName" based access to your instances

```
Dictionary<string,Race> races = new Dictionary<string,Race>();

  public void createRace(string raceName, Element element1, Element element2, AbilityScore stat1, AbilityScore stat2, AbilityScore stat3, AbilityScore stat4)
    {
        Race temp = new Race();
        temp.raceName = raceName;
        temp.primaryElement = element1;
        temp.secondaryElement = element2;
        temp.primaryAbility = stat1;
        temp.secondaryAbility1 = stat2;
        temp.secondaryAbility2 = stat3;
        temp.weakAbility = stat4;

        races.Add(raceName,temp);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks that seems to work, honestly didn't expect a response that fast.